# Incuding C++ header files in C, VS 2010

Tags: c++, c, header-files

I want to write a C code, say "test.c", and call some C++ functions from it.

I have a header file header.h which has functions defined in it
and a C++ file which has definitions of the functions.

I'm unable to figure out compilation commands and how to use the `extern` command. 
Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to write a C code, say "test.c" call some C++ functions from it.

Try something like this in your header:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
  void foo (void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

Then implement `foo()` in your .cpp file. Make sure that your .cpp file also includes the header.

Comment: @DeadMG: Too early in the morning here, I missed that. Fixed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. Can u also help me out in compilation commands as header file has to be compiled using cpp compiler and c file using c compiler and both have to be linked.

Comment: That input really helped.
But I've a problem here. I'm unable to define classes in header file(I've put it in between extern and it still didn't work) 
Why is that, is there a solution?

Comment: @neeradkumar: You cannot put C++ code (classes) into a header that is supposed to be used by C compiler. IOW, you cannot do that.